# Find strings and remove those lines

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to read all the text files from a directory, iterate through every file, and search for strings in the file and delete those lines. E.g.,

**sample.txt**

```
#Wrote for the configuration ideas

mag = some , db\m09oi, id\polki
jio = red\po9i8

[\]

@mag = denk
@jio = tea
```

I want to delete the lines having mag.

**Output**

```
#Wrote for the configuration ideas

jio = red\po9i8

[\]

@jio = tea
```

I tried:

```
Dir.glob("D:\\my_folder\\*.txt") do |file_name|

  value = File.read(file_name)
  change = value.gsub!(/[@m]ag/, "")
  File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts change }

end
```

But the lines aren't removed.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: It is better to read the file line by line and if a line contains `mag`, just omit it, and only write other lines to the new file.

Comment: To fix your current approach, you might try `change = value.gsub(/^.*\bmag\b.*\R?/, "")`. The use of word boundaries will justify the use of a regex (if you want to only match `mag` as a whole word).

Comment: `File.write(file_name, File.readlines(file_name).reject { |line| line[/^.*\bmag\b.*$/] }.join($/))`

Comment: @mudasobwa That approach is better with `line[/\bmag\b/]`, it will work faster. Please post with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks much for your time. +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is better to read the file line by line and if a line contains mag, just omit it, and only write other lines to the new file. 
>   — *Credits to @WiktorStribiżew*

```
File.write(file_name, File.readlines(file_name).reject do |line|
                        line[/\bmag\b/]
                      end.join($/))
```

Here we read the file, split by lines with [`IO#readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readlines), reject lines having `mag` as a single word inside (`"magistrate"` won’t be matched,) join it back with the line delimiter, specified for this particular platform (e.g. `\n` on unix) and write it back.

Comment: Thanks worked perfect and +1 for the alternate approach